# I have some trouble with path on selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to run the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/Users/Admin/Selenium_Driver"
driver = webdriver.Edge()
When I use executable_path in the webdriver, the code runs correctly. However, when I use the above code, it can't find the path. What could be causing this problem? Maybe it's related to using a Conda environment.
Can someone help me solve this issue? Thank you.